# Transparent QWebView with Qt5

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, transparent, qtwebkit

We used to use trick https://www.qt.io/blog/2009/06/30/transparent-qwebview-or-qwebpage to make QWebView transparent with Qt4 as following, but same code give us blank background with Qt 5.2. Is there any way I can make that work with Qt5?

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool);

if(m_pWebView)
{
    QPalette palette = m_pWebView->palette();
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, Qt::transparent);
    m_pWebView->page()->setPalette(palette);
    m_pWebView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, false);
    m_pWebView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
}
```

Comment: Looks like [QTBUG-29040](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29040) to me, which is still not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines worked for me under QT5.4

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
```